# Chrome on Android, font-weight not respected for system font

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, font-face, webfonts

**Here is a nice challenge for those interested:**

We knew `Roboto` font has a *thin* version, and such font can normally be specified via CSS using `font-weight: lighter` or weight value less than 400.

With `font-weight: 200; font-family: Roboto;` rule, we get Firefox on Android to pick the right version of font to display, as well as major desktop browsers (if such font exists).

Chrome on Android has a different idea: it always picks the Roboto *regular* font.

OK, maybe Chrome doesn't like the syntax, let's try a few alternatives:

- `font-weight: lighter; font-family: Roboto;`
- `font-family: 'Roboto Thin';`
- `font-weight: 200; font-family: 'Roboto Thin';`

Nope, chrome still likes the regular version better.

How about this one?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: 200;
    src: local("Roboto-Thin");
}

font-family: Roboto;
font-weight: 200;
```

Sadly no, as it turned to be a bug, marked as won't fix: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322658

Now, the team did offer an alternative:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: 200;
    src: local("sans-serif-thin");
}
font-family: Roboto;
font-weight: 200;
```

Which sadly doesn't work on our testing devices (OS 4.1.2 with Chrome stable/beta) neither.

Now the elephant in the room is fallback to web font, which, on Chrome beta, does work as they were fixed in http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=167557

But using a web font fallback for a default system font seem rather weird. Plus it does cause an extra download and delay content displays.

So I wonder if anyone has a better workaround for this problem?

---

Test cases:

- http://jsfiddle.net/4CDYW/13/
- http://jsfiddle.net/4CDYW/14/
- http://jsfiddle.net/4CDYW/15/

Comment: I should note that Opera also exhibit such issue, but Safari mobile (iOS) doesn't. So could be a Blink problem.

Comment: Also I have tried both `Roboto-Thin`, `Roboto Thin` or `RobotoThin`, just in case...

Answer (score 0):

I've used Google Web Fonts, with font-weight 300 and used 'Roboto' as the font name and not had a problem:

From http://www.google.com/fonts

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Comment: web font does work, as i have mentioned, but i am seeking a way to use local installed font.

Comment: Where did you get the font's from? I've just checked out my Roboto fonts locally and I have 'Roboto Light' as the name.

You can download the fonts your select from Google Web Fonts and use them locally by copying the font-face rules from the response from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700 and switching out the URL's for the local one.

Comment: i am referring to http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html, which does mention thin. now that you have mentioned it, i need to double check if android 4.1 indeed have such font.

Comment: I stand corrected: Android 4.1 does **NOT** have *Roboto Thin*, my best guess is Firefox fallback to a lighter font will Chomre does not. will report back.

Answer (score 0):

My mistakes: *Roboto Thin* does **not** actually exists on android 4.1 (to be honest i am not sure whether it's in 4.4, as no doc mentioned it)

so don't be misguided by http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html, the actual font list is in api doc: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.1.html#Fonts, where Thin is absent.

Now that it's clear only *Roboto Light* exists, i have tried above solutions again, and the Chromium team's suggestion are the only working solution:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-weight: 200;
    src: local("sans-serif-light");
}
font-family: Roboto;
font-weight: 200;
```

this will get both firefox and chrome to use the right font without any webfont fallback.